# CSS background-image not showing even with correct file name

Tags: css, html, background-image

I'm trying to use CSS divs to add images to my site. I'm using background-image:url(""); but the image doesn't appear when loading the site.
The images I'm referencing are in the same folder as my style.css, and I quadruple-checked that I wrote the file names correctly.
Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

CSS:

```
div#logo { 
    background-image:url(dm-button2.png);
    height: 120px; 
    width: 120px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background: blue; /* #333333; */
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: inline;
}
```

HTML: (Am I missing something here?)

```
<div id="logo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div#logo { 
    background:url(dm-button2.png) blue;
    height: 120px; 
    width: 120px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 100; /* #333333; */
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: inline;
}
```

try this, your second background is rewriting the first

Comment: That didn't work, but when I deleted the color attribute altogether it works! Kind of. Now it's zoomed in to the top right corner of the image.

Comment: and is your background transparent? because if yes, it must work, look here - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sAfyd/). There it is shown with transparent logo of one seo analyzator...

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
div#logo { 
    background-image:url(dm-button2.png);
    height: 120px; 
    width: 120px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: blue; /* #333333; */
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing Background image and background with something like this

```
background: blue url('dm-button2.png') no-repeat fixed center;
```

I am not 100% sure but i think having background-image followed by background, background will overwrite the background-image call since it loads in order

Answer (score 0):

example [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vKcaQ/)
start small and add the other attributes.

```
div#logo { 
    height: 120px; 
    width: 120px;
background:url(http://flyingmeat.s3.amazonaws.com/acorn4/images/Acorn256.png) 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The background image will not display if there is nothing to put a background image on... for example, all you have a div tags but nothing inbetween them.

Add at least a br tag or something to create some space for the image to be displayed.

Comment: he has the div's css width and height set for 120px so it will show just fine.